# Extracting the same values from a JSON object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with taking all values under the "id_ref_directory" keys.

I have a temp table:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE parsed_json(
    var_key text, 
    var_value text NOT NULL)
ON COMMIT DROP;
```

I prase a JSON into temp table:

```
INSERT INTO parsed_json(var_key, var_value)
SELECT * 
FROM json_each_text(var_in_json::json)
WHERE value IS NOT NULL and LENGTH(value) != 0;
```

I have var int[]:

```
var_territory_list := (SELECT var_value FROM parsed_json WHERE var_key = 'territory_custom');
```

And I have this value under "id_ref_directory" key:

```
[{"name_directory": "ЯПОНИЯ", "id_ref_directory": 38},
{"name_directory": "ЯПОН", "id_ref_directory": 39}, 
{"name_directory": "ЯП", "id_ref_directory": 40}]}
```

I need to write into `var_territory_list`this from JSON above (values of keys "id_ref_directory"):

```
38, 39, 40 -- Like an array (int[])
```

I thought that I could solve everything with simple operators like `#>` but I failed. Maybe it is necessary to do it through a cycle? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the array into rows:

```
postgres=# SELECT j.jsontext->'id_ref_directory' FROM (SELECT json_array_elements('[{"name_directory": "ЯПОНИЯ", "id_ref_directory": 38},
{"name_directory": "ЯПОН", "id_ref_directory": 39}, 
{"name_directory": "ЯП", "id_ref_directory": 40}]'::json) jsontext) as j;
 ?column? 
----------
 38
 39
 40
(3 rows)
```

If you really need an array, you can wrap it in an `ARRAY()` call:

```
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY(SELECT j.jsontext->'id_ref_directory' FROM (select json_array_elements('[{"name_directory": "ЯПОНИЯ", "id_ref_directory": 38},
{"name_directory": "ЯПОН", "id_ref_directory": 39}, 
{"name_directory": "ЯП", "id_ref_directory": 40}]'::json) jsontext) as j);
   array    
------------
 {38,39,40}
(1 row)
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)